# Maven: safe for concurrent execution?

Tags: maven, concurrency

Is Maven safe for concurrent execution?  i.e. can I have several

```
mvn compile
```

command running in separate directories at the same time, each of which may be updating `$HOME/.m2`?

Comment: The compile phase doesn't update anything in the local Maven repository. The compiler plugin is [thread safe for parallel builds](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3) however.

Comment: Thanks, if you want to add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @orid - the compile phase doesn't update the local repository, but it is preceeded by dependency download, which may update the local repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local repository is NOT safe for concurrent maven instances (see link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/MNG-2802 )

This is a common problem on Continuous Build/Integration systems.

Although at first glace this doesn't affect the 'compile' phase, as the compile phase depends on dependency resolution and   the updating of the local repository with downloaded artifacts it is still an issue.